# How do I turn on http compression?

Tags: apache-httpd, compression

I'm running a CentOS server and I want to save bandwidth, make pages faster, all that. How can I turn on http compression? Is it a module I enable for all sites? Can it be that simple?

Comment: Check out http://gzipwtf.com/. Here you can see which files served are compressed while being served by the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

Add this to your apache config:

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
</Location>
```

Obviously if the path your system uses for apache modules differs then you'll need to use the *correct* path.

Comment: For the CentOS 5 httpd rpm, mod_deflate is included and already loaded.  You do need to use the DEFLATE output filter as bahamat describes above.

Comment: I added the LoadModule to a conf in conf.d and yeah, after restarting apache it's already loaded. How can I tell if it's serving everything compressed and why would google keep telling me to compress everything? Guess those are questions best asked elsewhere.

Comment: If you look at the headers (each browser has its own way, or use a sniffer such as wireshark or tcpflow to see them) one of them will be something like `Content-Encoding:gzip`. You should use an actual desktop browser (e.g., firefox, chrome, etc) rather than a lower level client (lynx, curl, telnet, etc) because the lower level clients may not support/request/advertise compression capability.

Comment: I think the problem is I needed to add AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css to httpd.conf. Now it seems to be working.